# setting EDITOR variable for macvim

Tags: macvim, bash

seems like it would be a trivial thing. Does it matter if it's `.profile` or `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` or something else? And what to put in it? I have tried `export "EDITOR=vim"` and `export EDITOR=vim` and `export EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim"` and `export QWANDRY_EDITOR=vim` (I need this use qwandry), all in bash_profile. I've looked on SO and elsewhere and there doesn't seem to be one consistent solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put it in any of those files, although most users put it in `~/.bashrc` (if they're using bash). However, `EDITOR` should be set to `mvim`, not `vim`.